# How to set up a “tunnel” or a “proxy” on linux?

Tags: linux, proxy, tunnel

Some companies, like JavaPipe DDoS Protection, and AssetGateway are able to offer "proxies", where they are able to route traffic through their servers, to yours. The benefit of this being their servers are DDoS protected, meaning all your traffic gets filtered.

I would like to try and set this up myself, and am wondering what I could use to forward the traffic from a DDoS protected server I bought, to a clients server

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use [openvpn](/questions/tagged/openvpn) which will let you create a encrypted tunneled connection between two nodes.

[openvpn](/questions/tagged/openvpn) can be downloaded from [here](http://openvpn.net/).
On that page you will also find documentation and a simple explanation for setting this up between two machines in two different modes. Some distributions like [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) and derivates also have the software in their packaging system making it easy to install from there.

By using [openvpn](/questions/tagged/openvpn), you can, if done correctly take two separate networks and mesh them together into one network or include one machine outside of the network into the local network. The same software can also be used to include so called road-warriors which are users on the road that wish to have a secure connection to the local network, making it difficult for others to take a look at your network transmission data. The benefit with the road-warrior way is that the user can if done correctly use services on the local network just as they were physically on the local network.

Cheers.

Comment: I'd rather the client didn't have to do anything on their end. Is there any way to do this with openvpn?

Comment: I don't think so. Anything "tunnel" requires some form of two way handshake no matter if there is encryption or not in the picture. I am not so familiar with proxying, but I suspect that is a better way to go if you do not wish to set up software on one end of the chain.